# Deep linking with React, Expo and React-Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation, deep-linking

**NOTE:** Several questions are there with this topic but non of them matches my requirements.

I am somewhat new to react and react native (not to programming) and trying to create an application with below tech stack.

1. react-native
2. react-navigation
3. Expo

**Context** (Read if you feel so):
I was implementing login with twitter which is done on my backend server.

1. User clicks on a button in the app. It opens the WebBrowser (given in expo docs).
2. Authorization screen appears and user fills and authorize my twitter application.
3. I have used my server's URL as a callback in my twitter application so twitter finally redirects user to my server.

But to save the information namely access key and secret i need some user information as in who the user is.
An alternative approach could be that callback should be a deeplink redirecting it to the app providing access keys and secret and then my application makes a post request to my server.

**In nutshell**, i want to implement deeplinks in my application. There are so many articles and docs in react, react navigation and expo and i have read them almost 100 times and really got confused.

It would be great if someone can tell me what are the exact steps for deep links with react navigation, react native and expo